# JNI MattoBitmap Exception

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, bitmap

I have implemented camerax and turned give the "image proxy" output to jni function by turning it to bitmap successfuly and i have 2 function i got from opencv github which turn bitmap to mat then mat to bitmap

these are the function in jni

1-BitmapToMat(works pretty well i guess)

```
void bitmapToMat(JNIEnv * env, jobject bitmap,  Mat& dst , jboolean needUnPremultiplyAlpha){
    AndroidBitmapInfo  info;
    void*              pixels = 0;

    try {
        CV_Assert( AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &info) >= 0 );
        CV_Assert( info.format == ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888 ||
                   info.format == ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGB_565 );
        CV_Assert( AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixels) >= 0 );
        CV_Assert( pixels );
        dst.create(info.height, info.width, CV_8UC4);
        if( info.format == ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888 )
        {
            Mat tmp(info.height, info.width, CV_8UC4, pixels);
            if(needUnPremultiplyAlpha) cvtColor(tmp, dst, COLOR_mRGBA2RGBA);
            else tmp.copyTo(dst);
        } else {
            // info.format == ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGB_565
            Mat tmp(info.height, info.width, CV_8UC2, pixels);
            cvtColor(tmp, dst, COLOR_BGR5652RGBA);
        }
        AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
        return;
    } catch(const cv::Exception& e) {
        AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
        jclass je = env->FindClass("java/lang/Exception");
        env->ThrowNew(je, e.what());
        return;
    } catch (...) {
        AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
        jclass je = env->FindClass("java/lang/Exception");
        env->ThrowNew(je, "Unknown exception in JNI code {nBitmapToMat}");
        return;
    }
}
```

2- Mat to Bitmap(ıt gives me error with this function)

```
void MattoBitmap(JNIEnv * env,Mat src , jobject bitmap, jboolean needPremultiplyAlpha)
{
    AndroidBitmapInfo  info;
    void*              pixels = 0;

    try {
        CV_Assert( AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &info) >= 0 );  **//basically it gives me error in this line**
        CV_Assert( info.format == ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888 ||
                   info.format == ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGB_565 );
        CV_Assert( src.dims == 2 && info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows && info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols );
        CV_Assert( src.type() == CV_8UC1 || src.type() == CV_8UC3 || src.type() == CV_8UC4 );
        CV_Assert( AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixels) >= 0 );
        CV_Assert( pixels );
        if( info.format == ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888 )
        {
            Mat tmp(info.height, info.width, CV_8UC4, pixels);
            if(src.type() == CV_8UC1)
            {
                cvtColor(src, tmp, COLOR_GRAY2RGBA);
            } else if(src.type() == CV_8UC3){
                cvtColor(src, tmp, COLOR_RGB2RGBA);
            } else if(src.type() == CV_8UC4){
                if(needPremultiplyAlpha) cvtColor(src, tmp, COLOR_RGBA2mRGBA);
                else src.copyTo(tmp);
            }
        } else {
            // info.format == ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGB_565
            Mat tmp(info.height, info.width, CV_8UC2, pixels);
            if(src.type() == CV_8UC1)
            {
                cvtColor(src, tmp, COLOR_GRAY2BGR565);
            } else if(src.type() == CV_8UC3){
                cvtColor(src, tmp, COLOR_RGB2BGR565);
            } else if(src.type() == CV_8UC4){
                cvtColor(src, tmp, COLOR_RGBA2BGR565);
            }
        }
        AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
        return;
    } catch(const cv::Exception& e) {
        AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
        jclass je = env->FindClass("java/lang/Exception");
        env->ThrowNew(je, e.what());
        return;
    } catch (...) {
        AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
        jclass je = env->FindClass("java/lang/Exception");
        env->ThrowNew(je, "Unknown exception in JNI code {nMatToBitmap}");
        return;
    }
}
```

```
  java.lang.Error: java.lang.Exception: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:/Users/islam/AndroidStudioProjects/DriveFriend/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:53: error: (-215:Assertion failed) AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &info) >= 0 in function 'MattoBitmap'
    
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1173)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: java.lang.Exception: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:/Users/islam/AndroidStudioProjects/DriveFriend/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:53: error: (-215:Assertion failed) AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &info) >= 0 in function 'MattoBitmap'
    
        at com.islamozcelik.drivefriend.MainActivity.SayIamHere(Native Method)
        at com.islamozcelik.drivefriend.MainActivity$1.analyze(MainActivity.java:79)
        at androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis.lambda$setAnalyzer$1$ImageAnalysis(ImageAnalysis.java:371)
        at androidx.camera.core.-$$Lambda$ImageAnalysis$qO2F3Tn7pfTvGyL-EvT8WWE0F0w.analyze(Unknown Source:4)
        at androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysisAbstractAnalyzer.lambda$analyzeImage$0$ImageAnalysisAbstractAnalyzer(ImageAnalysisAbstractAnalyzer.java:87)
        at androidx.camera.core.-$$Lambda$ImageAnalysisAbstractAnalyzer$g-dcm6aZmGod2IWKPwN4CArIZzI.run(Unknown Source:8)
```

i have tried a lot of things but still dont know what the problem is ? anybody there that can help me with this ?